# Where can I permanently modify Directory[]?

Tags: files-and-directories, customization, initialization

First I set

```
SetDirectory["F:\\learning_mma"];Directory[](*ok,success*)
```

and then I quite the kernel:

```
Quit[]
```

an then

```
Directory[]
```

it output the `"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents"`.
So how can I modify Directory[] permanently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run `SetDirectory` in the kernel initialization file, [`init.m`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html).  You'll find it here:

```
SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel"}]
```

Comment: You mean to say that I add SetDirectory["F:\\learning_mma"] in the init.m?

Comment: Oh successful! thank you!